# "I better pass" auf Deutsch

Tags: english-to-german, phrase

How would you say **I better pass (I will better pass)** in terms of declining someone's ridiculous offer?

Google Translate suggests *"ich gehe besser vorbei"*, but it seems to me too straightforward. I don't believe Germans communicate that this way.

It is not just in terms of bidding, when two are rising the bets until one wants to quit.

Example:
I own a rare record priced $750. Someone offers me to sell it for $50 which seems both ridiculous and outrageous to me. I don't want to respond as "Sehr geehre/-r Frau/Herr, leider..."

Neither want I to ignore the message.
What I want to say is: "haha, I'll better pass".

Comment: Just ignore them or tell them what it costs and that's it :-) (Keep it ! It's vinyl !)

Comment: What is the situation, why and where did you get the offer?

Comment: An informal version would be "Lass' mal stecken."

Comment: "Nein, danke."  -  "Ohne mich."  - "Kein Bedarf." - "Das lass' ich wohl besser." - "Wohl kaum."  The possibilities are endless!

Comment: Someone offers you to sell your record? To sell or to buy? Sell it as an agent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could translate it almost literally with "nein, danke, lassen wir es lieber" ('no, thanks, let's leave it at that'), but in this case the reason for your refusal would not be transparent. Alternatively, you could say "das ist doch wohl ein Scherz!" ('you must be joking!').

Comment: "Nee laß ma (lieber)" paßt gut.

Comment: @DavidVogt Ja, man könnte es sogar noch krasser ausdrücken "lass ma stecken ;-)

Comment: Wow! There is a whole bunch of new words in both response and comments :) Thank you, gentlemen! I am accepting this one as an answer and opening my dictionary to learn new words and phrases.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something different. If the offer is ridiculous, your answer would still be polite.

I’m interpreting your ***I’ll pass*** like in a poker game when someone in the current round would pass instead of raising the bet. Or the player would dismiss the round if someone before raised the bet in a ridiculous way.

In that case you would say something of these. All of which are not indicating a reason for denial.

> Da muss ich leider passen (I’ll pass)

or

> Das muss ich leider ablehnen (I must deny)

in case the offer was ridiculously expensive. Or

> Das kann ich nicht annehmen (I can not accept that)

If the offer was ridiculously cheap.

Those are polite forms. The others are more like ***you’re gonna be kidding me?***

> Das ist wohl ein Scherz? (You’re joking/kidding?)

or

> Und das soll wahr sein? (This ain’t true?)

or

> Sie wollen mich wohl verarschen? (are you f... kidding me?)

or

> Und das soll ich Ihnen glauben? (I shall believe that?)

Comment: Der Hinweis auf das dt. passen verdient m.E. ein +1. Allerdings kenne ich das auch vornehmlich bei Gesellschaftspielen oder in einer Auktion zwischen Konkurrenten, wenn man nicht mitzieht/überbietet, nicht vom Handeln zwischen Anbieter und Nachfrager. "Das Angebot schlage ich aus." wäre noch höflich, aber bestimmt. "Für 50 dürfen Sie mal dran riechen" könnte man sagen um auszudrücken, wie deplaziert das Angebot war.

Comment: @userunknown true, there are so many variations on how to say that.

Answer (score 1):

I think trying to translate this phrase doesn't make much sense.

A typical reply in German in such a situation is *Das kann nicht Ihr Ernst sein!* (*You can't be serious!*)